# I left kimchi at room temperature for 7 hours. Can I still eat it?

Tags: kimchi

I accidentally left Sunja's kimchi at room temperature for 7 hours.  It started leaking.  It's in the fridge now.  Can I still eat it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

Answer (score 0):

Kinchi is a fermented food, then, let out for some time doesn't damage it, except if this is too much time, like days. May be you will experience more vinaigrette flavor, but it is a good indicator and depend of your preferable taste. Also Sunja's kimchi made a statement that they use only fresh and natural ingredients without any additives, and it is a good signal.